# Error:Module 'name' production: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework

I'm running my Java project in IntelliJ 14.1.1 and I'm using play framework.
For some reason I can't compile any part of the code in IntelliJ (even though everything is working perfectly in the play environment).
I get this error when trying to compile :

```
Information:5/26/15, 19:26 - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings in 1s 165ms
Error:Module 'doorman' production: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

'doorman' is the name of the project.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Is there anything (stacktrace maybe?) in the IntelliJ log? (Main Menu | Help | Show log...)

Comment: Related? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8154

Comment: @Meo the build.log is pretty long but it starts like that:
2015-05-25 11:21:09,529 [   4082]   INFO - .incremental.IncProjectBuilder - Module 'doorman' production: java.lang.NullPointerException
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.ProjectBuildException: Module 'doorman' production: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:945)
 at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:814)
 at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:637)

Comment: it's pretty similar but thing is that my project is written in java and that guys project is in scala so i cant download the plugin offered and fix it that way...

Comment: I have the same problem with Scala plugin 2016.3.8.
Replaced with version 2016.3.3 and problem is gone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recreated the entire project and imported it and it solved the problem.
Couldn't find any way to resolve this issue

Comment: For me removal of directory `~/.IntellijIdea<version>/system/compile-server/<project-name>_<hash>` worked well

Comment: For me rebuilding the project also worked (IntelliJ > Build > Rebuild Project)

Comment: I did all of those things plus removing play framework plugin and nothing worked.

Comment: "IntelliJ > Build > Rebuild Project" worked for me. Thanks NickGreen!

Comment: my issue was an IndexOutOfBoundsException and "IntelliJ > Build > Rebuild Project" worked for me, after trying several things myself

Comment: Rebuilding Project would work here

Answer (score 15):

For me, it was the "Scala plugin" version 2016.3.4.

Removed it from IDEA and installed [2016.3.3](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/idea/plugin/1347-scala) version.

Then everything started working.

UPDATE [2017-03-06]: With release 2016.3.9 (latest version), the bug is fixed,  it seems.

Comment: Yep, 2016.3.4 was the culprit for me too.

Comment: After rolling back, per above, I had to reimport the gradle project and do a full rebuild.

Comment: NB I just took the 2016.3.1 update and it bundled in the scala update; you'll need to roll it back, again.  Hopefully, it's still in your downloads folder!

Comment: Rollback from 2016.3.5 to 2016.3.3 helped me.

Comment: I got the same error in 2016.3.8. Asked for help on Scala Plugin issue tracker, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11328 
In my case the error occurred because I had an empty "output path" in one of modules (visible in File -> Project Structure) - I don't know how it happened. The error can happen even if the configuration is wrong for another module than the one being compiled.

Comment: Yup, I can testify that this was solved by installing the latest version of the scala plugin. I had version `2016.3.8` and after upgrading it to version `2016.3.8.16 eap`, the problem disappeared after a restart.

Answer (score 7):

This helped me:

```
Build->Rebuild project
```

Comment: I tried various solutions, like removing `.idea`, invalidating cache, restarting, `mvn clean compiler` etc .... but this solution solved my problem... thanks.

Answer (score 6):

delete  ~/.IntellijIdea/system/compile-server/_ usually happens after unexpected shutdown of intellij.

Comment: This worked for me.  However I am on windows so the directory was located here: C:\Users\username\.IdeaIC2018.1\system\compile-server

Answer (score 4):

This is a bug and it seems they are working on it. You can find a solution [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-11072)

Answer (score 0):

Removing play framework plugin solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I updated Scala plugin to v2016.3.8.
It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart
```

Doing this from the menu seems to clean all the secret directories